# Intuition behind the Endogeneity Test (the Hausman Test)

Tags: intuition, endogeneity, hausman

Suppose we have the following simple regression model (time series framework)"

$$y_1=\beta_0+\beta_1 y_2+\beta_2 z_1 +\beta_3 z_2 +u,$$

where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are exogenous and $y_2$ is either exogeneous or endougenous (this is what we want to check). In order to determine whether or not $y_2$ is endogenous, we can apply endogeneity test (Hausman test), which follows the following procedure:

Estimate the reduced form for $y_2$, i.e. estiamte the following equation:

$$y_2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1z_1+\alpha_2z_2+\alpha_3z_3+\alpha_4z_4+\nu,$$
where $z_3$ and $z_4$ are instruments. Since each $z_j$ is uncorrelated with $u$, $y_2$ is uncorrelated with $u$ if and only if $v$ is uncorrelated with $u$; this is what we want to test. The easiest way to test this is to include $v$ as an additional regressor in structural eqaution and to do a $t$ test, i.e. estimate the model

$$y_1=\beta_0+\beta_1 y_2+\beta_2 z_1 +\beta_3 z_2 +\gamma_1\widehat\nu+error.$$
I don't understad this part. We want to determine whether $u$ and $\nu$ are correlated, but how we unleash it by including $\widehat \nu$ at the structural equation? Doing so, we esimate the impact of $\widehat \nu$ on $y_1$, rather than on $u$. Please explain the intuition.

P.S. In my understanding in order to determine whether $u$ and $\nu$ are correlated, we can apply the following steps:

- Estimate $\widehat u$ from the structural equation,
- Estimate $\widehat \nu$ from the reduced eqaution,
- Regress $\widehat u$ on $\widehat \nu$.

Comment: Hi: I think it goes like this but hopefully someone else will give a better explanation. Think of $u$ as the same as $\gamma_{1} \hat{v}$ + error. This is allowed because the rest of the first and third equations are the same.  So, if $\gamma_1$ ends up being significant, then the "error" term doesn't do enough  to soak up all the noise. Therefore $v$ must soak some up also so it has to be correlated with $u$. Note that this only works because, if you disregard noise terms, then,  besides  the $\gamma$ term, the third equation is the same as the first equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation

$$ y_2 =  \alpha_0 + \alpha_1z_1 + \alpha_2z_2 + \alpha_3z_3 + \alpha_4z_4 + v $$

is usually called the *first stage*. The rationale for this test is that if $z_3$ and $z_4$ are good instruments, then $\hat{v}$ contains the potentially bad variation in $y_2$, i.e., the part that might be endogenous. If you are able to exclude $\hat{v}$ from the structural equation, you cannot reject that $y_2$ is exogenous.

Your intuition is not bad, but think about it as checking the correlation between $y_2$ and and $u$ instead. Residuals are uncorrelated with the regressors that made them (if unfamiliar with this check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474102/why-is-the-correlation-between-independent-variables-regressor-and-residuals-zer)) so the correlation between $\hat{u}$ and $y_2$ is zero by construction. Same problem applies to correlation between $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$.

Notice that the structural equation including $\hat{v}$ returns the IV estimate. Another way to understand this test is that if we interpret IV as OLS controlling for $\hat{v}$ and if we can exclude $\hat{v}$ from this equation then it is, arguably, uneccessary to control for $\hat{v}$; i.e, to use IV.

However, note that this is rarely a relevant test.

First, it assumes that the intrument(s) is(are) good. Second, if you do have a good(ish) instrument the test could fail to reject simply because the IV estimate is not very precise. In this case, I would still pick IV over OLS any day of the week since there is probably some theoretical reason to suspect endogeneity.

Also check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186116/iv-regression-endogeniety-and-wu-hausman-question) for more on the point about good instruments.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer! First, could you please explain why in order to determine whether $u$ and $v$ are coorelated we include $\widehat v$ in our structural equation? Doing this do we determine whether  $u$ and $v$ are correlated or not, and how? This is what I don't uderstand. As I usggested in my question, I am inclide to do it by regressing $\widehat u$ on $\widehat \nu$. Second, if this test is not relevant (as you highlighted in your answer), what is the alternative to this which yield to more precise results? Thanks again!

Comment: Np. Updated answer. There is no alternative and my point is that this is not something that is usually relevant to test for. To test for endogeneity you must first have a credible solution to the problem (that is IV). If the solution is credible, you don’t havet a problem anymore that you need test for. If solution is not credible, then you can’t (credibly) test for problem.